# The landing: part one (coded mystery)

Tags: cipher, story

You have just clambered out of bed when you hear a massive crash. The noise appeared to have come from your back garden. You peer out of your window and see a wooden box on the grass. While getting dressed, you make your way towards the box and take a look at it. The box is wooden and not locked. When you open it you see a keyboard. The keybard has a wire that seems to lead out of the box but when you lift the box up, you realise it stops. There is also a metal plate with some sort of code engraved. It reads:

*Crack the code to unlock

**1** 0 

**1** 1 

**1** 0
 
**1** 1

**1** 0

**11** 1



**1** 0

**10** 1

**10** 0

**1** 1

**1** 0

**1** 1



**1** 0

**10** 1

**1** 0

**10** 1

**10** 0



**1** 0

**10** 1

**11** 0

**10** 1



**1** 0

**10** 1

**1** 0

**100** 1



**1** 0

**10** 1

**1** 0

**10** 1

**1** 0

**1** 1



**1** 0

**10** 1

**10** 0

**1** 1

**1** 0

**1** 1



**10** 0

**1** 1

**101** 0



**1** 0

**10** 1

**100** 0

**1** 1



**1** 0

**10** 1

**11** 0

**1** 1

**1** 0



**1** 0

**10** 1

**1** 0

**100** 1



**1** 0

**10** 1

**100** 0

**1** 1



**1** 0

**11** 1

**10** 0

**1** 1

**1** 0



**1** 0

**10** 1

**10** 0

**1** 1

**10** 0*




You read and suspect that it was probably just a prank from next door but you enjoy puzzles and so decide to try and work out what it says.



 **This is the first part in a series of separate problems that is followed throughout a story. If somebody answers correctly then I will release the second part and so on. I will post hints as they are needed.**

Comment: Not to be picky, but about that formatting - is it a necessary part of the puzzle? If not, would you mind compacting it a little bit and not making a long column of at most four numbers?

Comment: The formatting is quite nessecary as it provides a sort of hint as to the layout of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says:

> Welcome aboard

The message is:

> Run length encoded binary.  The run lengths are the first digits on each line in binary.  This was evident from the right most digit always changing from zero to one.

The puzzle has an error:

> The l and the c need a linebreak between them

Comment: Well done. Will fix the problem.